# Safe Args: use list of parcelables

Tags: android, parcelable, android-architecture-navigation

I am using the Safe Args plugin with the new Navigation components for my Android project. Now I have an argument that is an array list of parcelables, is there a way to use this with the Safe Args Plugin?

Something like `app:argType=ParcelableArray`. This should be possible since there are bundle methods like `putParcelableArrayList()`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Currently i don't think there is a simple way to use list of parcelables with safe args,
But i have found some "hack" to make this work.
For example, i have object 'User' and it parcelable, i am declaring a new parcelable object 'Users' that extending ArrayList().

```
@Parcelize
data class User(var name: String, val age: Int): Parcelable

@Parcelize
class Users: ArrayList<User>(), Parcelable
```

Now i can set 'Users' as argument in navigation

```
<argument
      android:name="users"
      app:argType="com.navigation.test.Users"/>
```

And passing array list of parcelables between destinations:

```
 val user=User("Alex", 36)
 val users= Users()
 users.add(user)
 val action=MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToSecondFragment(users)
 NavHostFragment.findNavController(this@MainFragment).navigate(action)
```

And to retrieve them on other destination:

```
val users=SecondFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments).users
val user=users[0]
txtViewName.text=user.name
txtViewAge.text="${user.age}"
```

---

**Update:**

Support to list of objects coming in alpha8:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111487504

---

**Update 2:**
The approach mentioned above will not work in case the activity is recreated, as `@Parcelize` will not be able to store/restore the list.

The object will be store in the state bundle, however, it will store an empty list of objects.

Comment: Passing arrays of Parcelables is now possible by adding `[]` after the type you want to use, for example:
 `<argument android:name="users"  app:argType="com.example.User[]" />`

Comment: It works to pass the data/list but it does not keep the state, as it will not `Parcelize` the list for you.

This can introduce some bugs in case the process is killed and restored in the destination that receives the argument.

The state bundle will have a reference to the object passed as an argument, but the list will be empty.

It will also happen in case you use the `Users` class with `SavedStateHandle` inside a `ViewModel`. The list will be null as that data will not be saved.

@Alex

Answer (score 76):

Yes, since version 1.0.0-alpha08 you can now pass arrays of parcelable objects like this:

```
<argument
  android:name="users"
  app:argType="com.navigation.test.User[]"/>
```

For passing arrays of primitive types use for e.g. `app:argType="integer[]"`

Comment: Thanks. It works. Why google didn't write this done in their documents pages. So confused that every time I want something. I have to "Google" it instead of checking their useless "documentations" pages to find out. [navigation-pass-data](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-pass-data)

Comment: @YuanFu Well it's still just alpha release, there can be a lot of changes until this plugin becomes stable. I have made an [article](https://medium.com/@vepetruskova/using-safe-args-plugin-current-state-of-affairs-41b1f01e7de8) about safe args and I update it when there are new releases, maybe you'd find it useful

Comment: @LaVepe thanks for your comment and the article. I took a look at it. I'm having an error setting my array in the action details.

.setList(list) <- error = Array<(out) Object!>

Comment: @wesleyfranks it seems that you're trying to set list instead of Parcelable Array so the typing is failing. If you're using Kotlin, you can try convert your list with ```list.toTypedArray()``` method.

Comment: This should be the approved/accepted answer and the one that was accepted can cause issues as `@Parcelize` will not work and the data will not be stored in the state.

Answer (score 22):

An improvement to @LaVepe suggestion: as for Android Studio 3.4.2 you can pass Parcelable array with in-built feature of navigation editor by specifying Arguments for chosen destination. Just check 'Array' option after choosing your custom Parcelable class which should not be wrapped in any collection beforehand:

[image: Example]

**EDIT**
Here how it looks in xml:

```
<argument
        android:name="items"
        app:argType="com.company.domain.Item[]" />
```

In your Fragment/Activity code you might strictly pass a typed array of model Parcelable items. If you have non-array collection and write in Kotlin, it may be achieved with (if you have list beforehand) `list.toTypedArray()`.

Comment: @wesleyfranks edited post. If I right understand your problem mentioned in your another comment, you should really look into type fixing in Java/Kotlin code.